# Is there a way to update FX-Properties from another Thread without Platform.runLater() in kotlin?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I try to learn kotlin and have a problem with the TornadoFX thread.

In JavaFX, I could update observable Properties in another thread and the Updates will occur in the view without triggering using "Platform.runLater()"

**UPDATE**:

Everything I assumed  about Threadsafety in JFX is wrong!

Only update UI elements or Properties that are bound to the UI-Thread, with Platform.runLater(), Tasks or Animationtimer, never from Outside without Platform.runLater().

Though you should be use Platform.runLater() carefully, because you have not much controll over when what will be Added to the UI thread and it could cause some Iritations.

**Below this Point are my missconseptions**:

Here is what <strike>**works fine in JavaFX**</strike> works but is also wrong

```java
   @Fxml
   ProgressBar progress;

   @Fxml
   public void initialize(){
        DoubleProperty prop = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
        progress.progressProperty().bind(prop);
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExector();
        ex.execute(()->{
          while(true){
             Thread.sleep(2000);
             prop.set(prop.get()+0.1);

       }
   }


   }
```

Essentially the same Code but in Kotlin. It does **not work** and throws a Exeption:

> Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-3 TornadoFX

```
class test : View() {
    override val root: BorderPane by fxml("/views/primary.fxml")

    val counter = SimpleDoubleProperty()
    val progress: ProgressBar by fxid()

    init {
         thread{
                while(true){
                 Thread.sleep(2000)
                 counter.value += 0.1
                }
             }

        progress.bind(counter)


    }



}
```

I expected They would work alike. 
I could fix it with "Platform.runLater(()->...)", but i don't want to queue everything in the UI thread, when it already observes the properties. 
I thought it was the Whole purpose of the possibility to bind something to a UI element.

Am I using properties and bindings wrong or Is this a **TornadoFX issue** ?

Comment: no, it does not _work fine_ in fx, even though it doesn't throw immediately it's wrong and a time bomb. we __must not__ update properties of nodes in the scene graph off the fx thread,  no exception, no way around __period__

Comment: The thing that you say "works fine in JavaFX" is wrong.  You should not update properties in another thread when the properties are bound to UI elements.  That will trigger an update to the bound UI element from the other thread, which can cause race conditions and errors within the internal JavaFX system implementation.  So you should not do that.  A property bound to the UI should only ever be updated on the JavaFX application thread.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the core JavaFX observable/property/binding implementations automatically handle threading. When an observable/property/binding is updated the listeners are invoked on the thread that made the change. You either have to create your own binding that handles forwarding updates on the FX thread or you have to make sure the observables connected to the UI are always updated on the FX thread. And just to note: TornadoFX is a Kotlin framework built on top of JavaFX and thus ultimately uses to the JavaFX libraries—even if such use is "hidden" behind abstraction.

Comment: @kleopatra I am explicitly taught it to be used as Model property. the Bind, adds a Changelistener to property. And changelisteners are Thread-safe, because Observables are. This is why you should Use them. Thats how you update Models from a different Thread. It is not a Timebomb. Otherwise the MVVM or MVC pattern would not be possible to create. How do you smoothly and decoupled implement that otherwise? Especialy when you recieve asyncronously Data from a server. BUT the Property that you want to bind to a control, **must not be** Inside a UI-Thread.

Comment: @jewelsea
Could you explain the Part with the "can cause race conditions and errors within the internal JavaFX system implementation". I know that you should not manipulate any Property that is part of the FX-Scenegraph from another thread, and when there is a need, to interfere with something from outside you should Use "runLater()". But when you have a Model. Outside of the UI thread, you can simply Bind the Model to the UI element. Because the UI thread, Updates the Element, each tick. Properties In that Matter are Not threadsafe, but Listeners and Observers, for what I know.

Comment: why do you think that notification from Observables is thread-safe? It's an interface and I can't see anything in its doc that forces its implementations to guarantee such a thingy. Or is it anything specific to kotlin bindings?

Comment: The race condition is caused by one thread updating state while the FX thread reads the state. There's no proper synchronization so there's no guarantee the FX thread sees the correct state. This leads to _undefined behavior_. And no, as I already mentioned, none of the core `Observable` implementations are thread safe in any way. However, I'm not overly familiar with TornadoFX so it may add something in this regard.

Comment: @kleopatra Ok. I tested it i caused several problems. And I wrote my Professor. And you are right, it was my missconception of what is going on in the UI Update. He also told me the only reason, Platform.runLater() - use should reduced to a Minimum is, when the Updates somehow depend on each other and that could cause problems because you have little controll over when it is queued in the UI-Thread. 
Syncronisation from Data of another thread should be done ONLY within the UI Thread or queued in with runLater(). Thank you very much for making me aware of this!

Comment: thanks for listening and doing the necessary research - that's how we are all learning most efficiently :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I found out the Problem. 
I generated the Property Within a UI Element (View()). Properties Within FX-UI are bound to the UI Thread.</strike>

I just needed to generate make sure the Property I want to Bind, is OUTSIDE of the UI-Thread

Here is **a** propper way to avoid "runLater()"

```
object TestThread{
    val property = SimpleDoubleProperty()
    val elapsedSeconds = SimpleLongProperty(0);
    init{
        println("start thread")
        val timer = object : AnimationTimer() {
            override fun handle(now: Long){
                if((now - elapsedSeconds.value)> 100000000){
                    property.value+=0.01
                    elapsedSeconds.value = now
                }

            }
        }
        timer.start()

    }
}

class HelloWorld : View() {
    exception  
   thread

    override val root: BorderPane by fxml("/views/primary.fxml")

    val counter = SimpleDoubleProperty()
    val pro = ProgressBar()


    init {


        root.right{
            add(pro)
        }
        // Now  bind the Property from THE ANIMATION to the UI-element wich
        // wich Observes the changes of the Property with no problem at all
        val t = TestThread
        pro.bind(t.property);
        incr.bind(counter)


    }
}
```